# Matching between two series after manipulation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

> Suppose, we're given two series of integer numbers as X[..] And Y[..], which
>   has the same length. We can choose any position i of the series X[] and
>   doing the operation like , `X[i]=X[i] + 3`, `X[i + 2] = X[i + 2] + 2` , `X[i + 4] = X[i + 4] + 1`.
>   After manipulating the series with any number of time, is it possible to
>   find the same series like Y[..]?

I am thinking to implement it by brute force and normal combinational matching after manipulation. Is there any other process which can make it faster?

```
Given two series,

X [ 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 ,6,8 ]

Y [ 1, 5, 6 ,6, 7 ,7,9 ]

if i=2 then 
X [ 1, 5, 3 ,6, 5 ,7,8 ]

Y [ 1, 5, 6 ,6, 7 ,7,9 ]
and if i=3 then 
X [ 1, 5, 6 ,6, 7 ,7,9 ]

Y [ 1, 5, 6 ,6, 7 ,7,9 ]

Matches the series.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see that for every index p resulting cell could be represented as

```
Y[p] = X[p] + F(p-4) + 2 * F(p-2) + 3 * F[p]
```

where F[p] is number of operation at p-th index.

So you have system of p linear equations for p unknowns Fi.
This is tridiagonal (sparse) system, it could be solved with some fast methods or with usual Gaussian elimination.

System might be inconsistent - in this case there are no solutions

Answer (score 1):

Since an operation at index *i* modifies only elements present at index *i*, *i + 2* and *i + 4*, that is, all indices >= *i*, we can build a greedy algorithm which iterates over the array X from left-to-right and at every index *i* compares the value with array Y.

- Case *X[i]* > *Y[i]*: Then it's not possible to update X[i] to Y[i], hence return `not possible`.
- Case *X[i]* == *Y[i]*: Then continue iterating over the next element at *i + 1*
- Case *X[i]* < *Y[i]*: If *(Y[i] - X[i]) mod 3 != 0*, then return `not possible`, else compute `m = (Y[i] - X[i])/3` and increment `X[i] by 3 * m`, `X[i + 2] by 2 * m` and `X[i + 4] by m` and continue iterating.

If we reach the end of array X, then it means it's possible to construct array Y from X using these operations.

Overall time complexity of the solution is **O(n)**.